# Why is :hover not working in chrome devtools?

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome-devtools

I am testing the tooltip component in the Angular component library below:

- https://ngx-ndbx.frameworks.allianz.io/documentation/tooltip/overview

I want to leverage Chrome's Devtool's :hover functionality, which means that I want to use the functionality below
[image]
But when I tried it on the tooltip element mentioned in the link above, it doesn't work. Could anybody tell me why?

Comment: Probably because the functionality does not get triggered via CSS `:hover`, but via a JavaScript event.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for this information. I'll try calling javascript directly in chrom devtool's console to make test it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the event bound to the element is "mouseenter" instead of "hover", so I did the following to make it work

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("mouseenter", false, true);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```